# Socket.io is not refreshing React component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have a Server and Client with sockets, the connection is working between them, but my React component is not refreshing.

My component is a publication that is printed by an array of elements, and I get all this information from and API (Express) connected to a MySQL database.

This is my React file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './component.css';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import Msg from './components/Msg';
import ItemMsg from './components/ItemMsg';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
let socket = io('http://localhost:8082');

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ids: []
    };

  }


  componentDidMount() {

    socket.on('update:component', (data) => {

       // Debug line
        console.log('recived message:', data);

      // Update state
      this.setState(prevState => {

        // Get previous state
        const { ids }  = prevState;

        // Add new item to array
        ids.push(data);

        // Debug line
        console.log('new state:', ids);

        // Return new state
        return { ids };
      });
    });

    fetch('/todos/ids')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({ids: responseJson.data})
      console.log(responseJson.data);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar/>
        <Msg/>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.ids.map((i, k) =>
                <li key={k}><ItemMsg idfromparent={i.ID_Publicacion}/></li>
          )
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

This is my Server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var messages = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "I'm a message",
  author: "I'm the author"
}];

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept-Type');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
})

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send("Hello World!");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Alguien se ha conectado con Sockets');

  socket.on('update:component', function(data) {
    socket.emit('Thanks', data);
    console.log(data);
  });
});

server.listen(8082, function() {
  console.log("Server corriendo en http://localhost:8082");
});
```

Insert component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import avatar from '../avatar.jpg'
import '../component.css'
import io from 'socket.io-client';
let socket = io('http://localhost:8082');


class Msg extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {value: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;

    // On submit of the form, send a POST request with the data to the server.
    fetch('/todo/meterla',{
      method: 'POST',
      body:JSON.stringify({
        publicacion: self.refs.task.value
      }),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    })
    .then(function(response){
      return response.json()
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log('json:', data);
      socket.emit('update:component', data );
    });
  }

 componentDidMount(){
   socket.on('update:component', (data) => {
     // Update state
     this.setState(prevState => {

       // Get previous state
       const { ids }  = prevState;

       // Add new item to array
       ids.push(data);

       // Return new state
       return { ids };
     });
   });
 }

 handleChange(event) {

    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

  render(data) {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="post" action="index.html" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <img className="avatar" src={avatar} alt="" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Escribe algo" ref="task" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Publicar" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Msg;
```

---

this is the result of the logs
[image]

Comment: what's exactly the problem? did you get any errors?

Comment: Try to debug `{ console.log( this.state.ids) }`

Comment: ^^ add that in `render()`

Comment: and post the result ^^

Comment: Also  what is the log of `fetch`? ( please update your question )

Comment: I want to automatically refresh the component when I insert a data in the database, and thats why i've implemnted the websockets. The fetch brings me a select from the database

Comment: try my `fetch` implementation` and post the log

Comment: what are you usign for the database? `mysql` ?

Comment: yes i'm using mysql

Comment: and i just added your fetch but the websocket still doesn't refreshing the component. It insert the data in the database but it still doesn´t refresh the component to show it in the screen

Comment: that's the problem i don't know how to do it

Comment: ok, where / when are you usign `insert` ??

Comment: In other component i'm going to update the question with that component

Comment: Connect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508560/express-server-receiving-post-request

Comment: I added a new answer,  the  problem is your implementation of `socket.io`

Comment: also that's not the `mysql` code

Comment: this is wrong  `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`

Comment: should be `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}`

Comment: please update your code

Comment: are you sure everything is working ??

Comment: I need to see your socket.io implementation as well

Comment: Please try to upload the app at github, I can't fix all your code :(

Comment: ok, let me do that

Comment: and please update your code ( again )

Comment: I've updated, it isn't show any errors but still doesn't refresh my component

Comment: you are missign a lot of  stuff...

Comment: where is the result of `console.logs` ???

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: you forgot to use: `handleChange(event)`

Comment: There is the handleChange(event)

Comment: post the `github` link...

Comment: node_modules are missing because my internet is not the best a i didn't put it to save time uploading the files https://github.com/RamsesSerna/websockets_react/tree/master

Comment: why are two `servers` ?

Comment: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /socket.io/socket.io.js from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8081/.`

Comment: the problem is your setup `server` / `socket-io` / `react`

Comment: One is my API and the other are my websockets

Comment: I can't help you here, your question should be more specific try to add more details and all errors / logs

Comment: I'll take a look at github ^^

Comment: You have multiple issues: https://github.com/RamsesSerna/websockets_react/issues

Comment: Please consider closing this question and ask a different question for `each` issue.

Comment: Possible duplicated:[stackoverflow.com/questions/39187049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187049/set-up-react-component-to-listen-to-socket-io)

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

> I want to automatically refresh the component when I insert a data in the database, and thats why i've implemnted the websockets. The fetch brings me a select from the database

I guess you mean every time you send a `post` request trough `handleSubmit()`, right?

## Post request

Handle your post request with `express`:
You need to emit a custom event every time you send the `post` request:

> Emits an event to the socket identified by the string name. Any other parameters can be included.

```
app.post("/foo", function(req, res, next) {
    io.sockets.emit("foo", req.body);
    res.send({});
});
```

See: [docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack)

## Get value from input

> In HTML, form elements such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with setState().

See: [Controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

```
 // Set state
 this.state = {value: ''};
 ...

 handleChange(event) {
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 }
 ...

 // Render
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

## Handling Events

> This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback

```
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

See: [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

## Setup react component + socket.io

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
...
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    ComponentWillMount(){
        this.socket = io();
    }
}
```

See: [Set up React component to listen to socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187049/set-up-react-component-to-listen-to-socket-io)

## Listen for event

> Register a new handler for the given event.
>   See: [docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-on-eventname-callback)

You are only `updating` the state only one time on `fetch()`, trigger `updateState` inside a listener:

```
ComponentDidMount(){

    // Listen for custom event and add handler
    this.socket.on('update:component', (data) => {
    ...
```

## Using state correctly

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

Do Not Modify `State` Directly, the only place where you can assign `this.state` is the constructor:

```
        this.setState(prevState => { 

            // Get previous state
            const { ids }  = prevState;

            // Add new item to array
            ids.push(data);

            // Return new state 
            return { ids };
    });
}
```

## Render

> JSX allows embedding any expressions in curly braces so we could inline the map() result

```
{
    this.state.ids.map((i, k) =>
        <li key={k}><ItemMsg idfromparent={i.ID_Publicacion}/></li>
    );
}
```

## Github

[websockets_react/issues/1](https://github.com/RamsesSerna/websockets_react/issues/1)

## Resources

- Socket.io: [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/#)
- React-state: [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
- Npm-package: [react-socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-socket-io)
- Learn: [React + socket.io](http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/06/16/reactjs-and-socket-dot-io-chat-application/)

Comment: it shows me this error "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

in this part:

handleChange(event) {

     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

Comment: you forgot to bind: `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`